# crc calculation for modbus

Tags: c, crc, modbus, crc16, rs485

Hi i am new to modbus RS485 i am unable to find the type of crc  for the given polling query.I am having the following modbus protocol.

```
01 37 37 1D 30 30 33 1D 30 03 34 37 33 39 37 04
01 37 37 1D 31 31 31 1D 30 1D 1B 5B 43 03 36 34 38 32 38 04 
01 37 37 1D 30 31 30 1D 30 1D 03 35 34 34 30 30 04
```

for the above modbus polling query i am unable to find the correct crc method and calculation.Please guide me to do correct way of crc calculation method.